# JQuery Ui and Electron

Tags: jquery, node.js, electron

I've recently started trying to make a desktop application using [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) and got Jquery working in the app.

I installed the following packages with `NPM install package -save`

**Node package dependencies:**

```
"electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.0",
"jquery": "^2.1.4",
 "jquery-ui": "^1.10.5"
```

And I'm using the following code to run Jquery and Jquery Ui

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jQuery');
require("jquery-ui");
```

**problem:** Jquery is loaded across the app, but `UI` isn't.

HTML EG:

```
<div id="bod">
  text
</div>
<script>
  $( "#bod" ).click(function(){
      var div = $("<div></div>").load("./html/testDialogue.html" );
      console.log( div );// jquery works like expected
      $(this).dialog();// UI not apart of JQuery extensions.. or loaded at all
  });
</script>
```

Comment: run `$.ui.version` to see if the jquery UI is loaded or not

Comment: which error You are getting in your inspector console of the electron build provide that

Answer (score 5):

For anyone else like me who came across this trying to globally load jQueryUI into your electron app - the best way to do this is not to install the jquery-ui NPM package, but to download the minified jQueryUI script from the CDN, store it locally in a resource folder and include it in your index directly below the line declaring your global jQuery variable and above the renderers you want to use it in, like so:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
<script src="../assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="render.js"></script>
```

This will give access to all jQueryUI functions via the global jQuery variable within your render scripts.

Comment: thanks @Morgan, this helps in Electron.
either <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
or in html page's js file need to have 
let $ = jQuery = require('jquery'); 
global.$ = global.jQuery = $; 
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

Answer (score 4):

The [jquery-ui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui) package is specifically made to be built after the installation.

Try the [jquery-ui-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui-dist) package instead: `npm i jquery-ui-dist`

Then you can just require it like this:

```
var $ = jQuery = require('jquery')
require('jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your libraries as Globals and not as AMD modules you can install the dependencies with bower and add the scripts to your index.html file as you would in a regular web site. In the case of Jquery you would still need to require it and declare the globals because Jquery detects in which context is running.

```
// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

But for JqueryUI I would recommend installing it as global. Is possible that JqueryUI is also detecting the context. If that's the case it should infer there are no Global variable to be attached on. Here they say how to use it as an AMD module.

https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/

Answer (score 0):

In case jQuery-UI dialog import that module by:

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/dialog';

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround to use `JQuery UI` with `electron`. Install JQuery UI with any package manager (like `npm`) and use it as like the web as given below,

```html
<!-- Insert this line above script imports  -->
<script>if (typeof module === 'object') {window.module = module; module = undefined;}</script>

<!-- normal script imports etc  -->
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>    
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>    

<!-- Insert this line after script imports -->
<script>if (window.module) module = window.module;</script>
```

It's more simple and generic solution to use JQuery UI with the electron. The benefits of using by the given way are it works for both browser and electron with the same code,
Fixes issues for ALL 3rd-party libraries (not just jQuery) without having to specify each one,
Script Build / Pack Friendly (i.e. Grunt / Gulp all scripts into vendor.js) and
does not require `node-integration` to be false

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Morgan, this helps in Electron.
either Add the bellow script in html file

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
```

or in html page's js file need to have

```
let $ = jQuery = require('jquery'); 
global.$ = global.jQuery = $; 
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;
```